# combining user defined tidyverse helper and main functions for packagedevelopment in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyr, r-package

I would like to source an external helper function within a main function, for package development. I have provided a simplified example below with the desired results by programming in tidyverse the long way. R is producing a "problem with mutate", when the helper function is programmed within the main function. Suggestions for working around this issue?

data frame

```
library(tidyr);library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
(df=data.frame(
  Yrs_Before=sample(1:8,3), #number of years in the before period specified  
  Yrs_After=sample(1:8,3), #number of years in the after period specified
  Before.Yr_1=sample(1:8, 3),# some number of counted observations in year 1 of the before period.
  Before.Yr_2=sample(1:8, 3),
  Before.Yr_3=sample(1:8, 3),
  Before.Yr_4=sample(1:8, 3),
  Before.Yr_5=sample(1:8, 3),
  Before.Yr_6=sample(1:8, 3),
  Before.Yr_7=sample(1:8, 3),
  Before.Yr_8=sample(1:8, 3),
  After.Yr_1=sample(1:8, 3),# some number of counted observations in year 1 of the after period.
  After.Yr_2=sample(1:8, 3),
  After.Yr_3=sample(1:8, 3),
  After.Yr_4=sample(1:8, 3),
  After.Yr_5=sample(1:8, 3),
  After.Yr_6=sample(1:8, 3),
  After.Yr_7=sample(1:8, 3),
  After.Yr_8=sample(1:8, 3)
  
))
```

helper function

```
sums_avg <- function(.data, crashes, yrs, avg) {#sums corresponding rows given the number of years specified 
  .data %>%
    dplyr::rowwise() %>% dplyr::mutate(if(avg==FALSE){
      cumsum(c_across(matches(crashes)))[.data[[yrs]]]} else #otherwise provides mean for the corresponding rows given the number of years specified
        {rowMeans(c_across(matches(crashes)))[.data[[yrs]]]
          })
}
```

main function

```
count_analysis_table=function(.data){
  
  .data |> dplyr::rowwise() %>% dplyr::mutate(
    summed_before_counts=sums_avg(crashes="Before.Yr", yrs="Yrs_Before",avg=FALSE),
    summed_after_counts=sums_avg(crashes="After.Yr", yrs="Yrs_After",avg=FALSE),
    avg_before_counts=sums_avg(crashes="Before.Yr", yrs="Yrs_Before",avg=TRUE),
    avg_after_counts=sums_avg(crashes="After.Yr", yrs="Yrs_After",avg=TRUE),
    predicted_before_counts= log(before_counts)^(-0.312),
    predicted_after_counts= log(after_counts)^(-0.340) #misc. column needed for auxiliary functions
  )
}
```

results in "Problem with 'mutate()' column 'summed_before_counts' x argument ".data" is missing, with no default. The error occurred in row 1"

```
df %>% count_analysis_table()
```

alternative

```
count_analysis_table=function(data){

  data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
      summed_before_counts=
        ifelse(
          Yrs_Before == 1, rowSums(across(Before.Yr_1)),
          ifelse(
            Yrs_Before == 2, rowSums(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_2)),
            ifelse(
              Yrs_Before == 3, rowSums(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_3)),
              ifelse(
                Yrs_Before == 4, rowSums(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_4)),
                ifelse(
                  Yrs_Before == 5, rowSums(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_5)),
                  ifelse(
                    Yrs_Before == 6, rowSums(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_6)),
                    ifelse(
                      Yrs_Before == 7, rowSums(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_7)),
                      ifelse(
                        Yrs_Before == 8, rowSums(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_8)),"")))))))),
      
      
      avg_before_counts=
        ifelse(
          Yrs_Before == 1, rowMeans(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_1)),
          ifelse(
            Yrs_Before == 2, rowMeans(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_2)),
            ifelse(
              Yrs_Before == 3, rowMeans(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_3)),
              ifelse(
                Yrs_Before == 4, rowMeans(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_4)),
                ifelse(
                  Yrs_Before == 5, rowMeans(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_5)),
                  ifelse(
                    Yrs_Before == 6, rowMeans(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_6)),
                    ifelse(
                      Yrs_Before == 7, rowMeans(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_7)),
                      ifelse(
                        Yrs_Before == 8, rowMeans(across(Before.Yr_1:Before.Yr_8)),"")))))))),
      
      
      
      summed_after_counts=
        ifelse(
          Yrs_After == 1, rowSums(across(After.Yr_1)),
          ifelse(
            Yrs_After == 2, rowSums(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_2)),
            ifelse(
              Yrs_After == 3, rowSums(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_3)),
              ifelse(
                Yrs_After == 4, rowSums(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_4)),
                ifelse(
                  Yrs_After == 5, rowSums(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_5)),
                  ifelse(
                    Yrs_After == 6, rowSums(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_6)),
                    ifelse(
                      Yrs_After == 7, rowSums(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_7)),
                      ifelse(
                        Yrs_After == 8, rowSums(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_8)),"")))))))),
      
      
      avg_after_counts=ifelse(
        Yrs_After == 1, rowMeans(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_1)),
        ifelse(
          Yrs_After == 2, rowMeans(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_2)),
          ifelse(
            Yrs_After == 3, rowMeans(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_3)),
            ifelse(
              Yrs_After == 4, rowMeans(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_4)),
              ifelse(
                Yrs_After == 5, rowMeans(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_5)),
                ifelse(
                  Yrs_After == 6, rowMeans(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_6)),
                  ifelse(
                    Yrs_After == 7, rowMeans(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_7)),
                    ifelse(
                      Yrs_After == 8, rowMeans(across(After.Yr_1:After.Yr_8)),"")))))))))
}
```

desired result

```
df %>% count_analysis_table()
Yrs_Before Yrs_After Before.Yr_1 Before.Yr_2 Before.Yr_3 Before.Yr_4 Before.Yr_5 Before.Yr_6 Before.Yr_7 Before.Yr_8 After.Yr_1 After.Yr_2 After.Yr_3 After.Yr_4 After.Yr_5 After.Yr_6 After.Yr_7 After.Yr_8 summed_before_counts avg_before_counts summed_after_counts avg_after_counts
1          7         6           2           5           6           3           3           1           3           1          4          3          4          5          1          4          3          2                   23  3.28571428571429                  21              3.5
2          8         3           6           4           1           5           1           8           2           6          6          7          7          7          2          5          6          5                   33             4.125                  20 6.66666666666667
3          3         2           3           6           2           8           4           5           7           3          1          5          2          1          3          7          1          7                   11  3.66666666666667                   6                3
```